# google calendar sync with full calendar io

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have developed event entry with `jquery` and `php` in `full-calendar io`. Now I want to add google calendar sync with this. How can I do that? I have read the documentation. In the events parameter I have to add events:

```
{ googleCalendarId: 'abcd1234@group.calendar.google.com' }
```

but I already added a `php` file (`load.php`) parameter. How I can use both of them together?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
editable:true,
header:{
 left:'prev,next today',
 center:'title',
 right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
events: 'load.php',
selectable:true,
selectHelper:true,
select: function(start, end, allDay)
{
var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD");
var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD");

 $("#form1").toggle();

//alert(title);
     $("#submit").click(function() {

var title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
     if(title)
 {

  var tname="Rayhan";
  var course=document.getElementById("course").value;
  console.log(course);
  var email="showrov@test.com";
  var descrip=document.getElementById("descrip").value;
  $.ajax({
   url:"insert.php",
   type:"POST",
   data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, tname:tname, course:course, 
   email:email, descrip:descrip},
   success:function()
   {
    calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    alert("Added Successfully");
   }
  });
 }//
 })


},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using by using the Event Sources feature. This allows you to define more than one source of data for your calendar events.

Simply replace

```
events: 'load.php'
```

with

```
eventSources: [
  'load.php',
  { googleCalendarId: 'abcd1234@group.calendar.google.com' }
]
```

Now your calendar will load events from both locations. It is documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources.

You must also ensure that you carry out the other setup steps documented in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar to get your Google Calendar feed working.